# How to send a password with special characters by using Expect module?

Tags: perl, passwords, expect.pm

I have a big problem with special characters of Perl.

I'm trying to establish a Telnet connection.

So, after the command "Telnet $ipAddress" I have to send the credentials.

I have done this way:

```
my $exp = new Expect;

$exp->send("username");
$exp->send("@password");
```

The problem is that my password has the @ character as first character and it is a special character.

I have already tried with `'@password'`, `"\@password"` or `"\\@password"`, but the login fails.

How can I get my password to work?

Comment: Try putting it in single quotes `'@password'`

Comment: Have you tried setting `$Expect::Exp_Internal = 1;`? I'm no expert on Expect but I'd, uh, expect it to be rather brittle when faced with programs like telnet that want to talk to a terminal and do fancy things like turning echo on and off. If `@` is in any way special to Expect, perhaps you need `"\\\@password"` or, simpler, '\@password'. Failing that, communicating with the service yourself using `Net::TCP` or something may be more robust.

Comment: I have already tried with single quotes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have tried to set $Expect::Exp_Internal = 1; and I saw that anyway my script send the correct password.

Comment: But the login fails. I don't know why. Thank you anyway for your help.